# Changing Site Background on button (and carrying it over to all pages on site)

Tags: theming

i'm trying to create a drupal site where under the logo, there would be three options visisble (light, dark, color), and once the user clicks on one of them, the site background will change.

now i know that this is easy to do with javascript (button, changing css background-image element)

but, how can i carry it over so that if the user clicks on a link on the site, the background-image stays the same without revolting to default?

i couldn't find any resources on how to do it, but i would gladly appreciate all of your help and anyone else on the interwebs with the same idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You could change the background with JavaScript and also save that preference in the user's Local Storage - which is basically a cookie that doesn't get sent to the server. It gets erased when cookies get erased.

First you need a JavaScript function to check that LocalStorage is available. Here is the function I use, cribbed from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427636/check-if-localstorage-is-available):

```
function localStorageTest(){
  var test = 'test';
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(test, test);
    localStorage.removeItem(test);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You'll throw an exception if the localStorage object is not available (e.g. if cookies are completely disabled), so that's why the try/catch.

Then you need to check for a preference when the page loads. I'm using jQuery here:

```
if (localStorageTest()) {
  var bgcolor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
  $('#page').css('background-color', bgcolor);
}
```

Finally, some code to set the preference - assuming here we are setting the same color as the button. You could use another attribute on the element to store the value. jQuery again:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var bgcolor = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('#page').css('background-color', bgcolor);
  if (localStorageTest()) {
    localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', bgcolor);
  }
};
```

Just to add some Drupal to this answer, there is a [Local Storage](https://www.drupal.org/project/local_storage) module that doesn't quite do this yet, but could potentially work if you set up a custom form and send the color choice as an AJAX form submit.

Also consider the [Session Cache API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_cache) module if you are going to elaborate on this example - it won't do what this example does, but it can help perform similar tasks.

I haven't tested this code, so there may be errors - consider it at least a roadmap to accomplishing the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Sweaver](https://www.drupal.org/project/sweaver)  module

> Sweaver offers a visual interface for completely changing your Drupal theme without knowing any CSS. Through a bar that sits at the bottom of your screen, you can change the fonts, colours, dimensions etc of all your design elements and see the changes real-time. If you are happy with the changes, you can easily save it as a revision to activate immediately or save for later.
>
> Advanced users will find a highly pluggable and configurable system that allows full manipulation off the interface and extendability of the functionality.

Have a look on some similar modules

[Flexible Colors](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexicolor)  - Flexicolor provides a flexible method for Drupal Designers to provide content administrators with ways to color text and backgrounds on different parts of the site.

[DesignKit](http://drupal.org/project/designkit) - DesignKit is a small API module lets themes provide options for customizing colors and images.